# can I update platform version on new sandbox

Tags: apex, api, sandbox, sandbox-refresh, pre-release

I created a new sandbox but since its a copy from production it is on API 44 all other sandboxes are API 45. is there a way to manually update the API version on the newly created sandbox to API 45?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please read dedicated article about it [Sandbox Preview Instructions for the Salesforce Spring '19 Release](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2018/12/spring-19-release-sandbox-preview-instructions.html).

According to its image [image]

you can't update sandbox API version manually. You have to wait for Production upgrade and after that do one more sandbox refreshing.

---

to check date when upgrading is planned use [status site](https://status.salesforce.com/instances/NA89/maintenances). For example, for NA89 instance Spring'19 release is planned on Feb 09